# Whats the difference between new $variable and new my_model?

Tags: php, class, variables

I've been making my own PHP Framework, I got this issue I can't find the answer, so to make it as a pattern I coded this way :

```
class post_control extends LoopControl
{
    var $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $classname = get_class($this);
        $this->model = new $classname();
    }

}
```

i get this error :

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/LoopWork/admin/core/model/Form.class.php on line 23<

Question 2:

I'm really using so much memory? How ?

Fact 1:

If I code new post_model();  I don't get this error.

Considering the fact 1 I assume there's a difference between these ways of making a new stance of a class.

Thanks already !

Comment: If you do it manually you instantiate `post_model` but by variable you are recursively instantiating `post_control`. One call to the constructor, and down the rabbit hole you go.

Comment: jep, you end up having an infinite recursion...

Comment: So in other words, you are doing two completely different operations here, one of which is recursive and eats all your memory. Did you mean to do some string operation on `$classname` to convert it into the model name?

Comment: Fu. Lol. yeah... gotta explode it and concatenate "model"

Thanks man !  It was kind of a distraction.. ty ty !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you basically create an instance of `post_control` an infinite number of times. This is the reason your script consume all memory.

```
class post_control extends LoopControl
{
    var $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $classname = get_class($this);
        $this->model = new $classname(); // this is the line where you instantiate a 
        //new post_control, and again post_control constructor is call, and a new instance
        //is created.. and so on for infinite times
}

}
```

Comment: Ty ty !  my new code is working ! It was kinda a distraction, Thanks ! `$aux = explode('_',getclass($this); $classname = $aux[0].'_model'`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you *are* using up all the system's memory. And that's because your constructor creates an infinite recursion:

```
class post_control extends LoopControl
{
    var $model;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $classname = get_class($this); // evaluates to 'post_control'
        $this->model = new $classname(); // equiv to new post_control();
    }

}
```

Upon creating a `post_control`, it will try to create another `post_control` for its `$model` property. This, in turn, will invoke the same constructor which will try to create a new `post_control` for its own `$model` and so on and so forth to eternity...

Comment: Ty ! Wish I could Vote Up ! hehe

Comment: @rcBytes: np! Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

`$classname` is `post_control`, not `post_model` in your example. You are calling the constructor recursively. Infinite recursion consumes all the memory available, thus produces fatal error.

Comment: Yea ! Thanks ! It was kind of a discraction, it is working noW ! Thanks ppl !  the new code : 
>$aux = explode("_", get_class($this));
   $classname = $aux[0]."_model";
   $this->model = new $classname();